# How to search through a list of objects nested inside an array with Spring data MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have got a collection of documents and each documents contains a nested array of objects.

```
{
  "id": "309324739",
  "debters": [
    {
      "user": {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "internal": true
      },
      "debt": 1463,
    },
    {
      "user": {
        "name": "Alex Tree",
        "internal": false
      },
      "debt": 53443,
    },
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to return find the document by **id** and then find inside the **debters** list that has a **false** flag?

I tried the following query...

```
Debters findByIdAndDebters_User_InternalIsFalse(@Param("id") String id,);
```

But I'm getting an error saying that it can find "internal" property. What am I doing wrong and how can I loop through array using this magic mongo repository query?

Answer (score 0):

you need to write a native query for that which is similar to
    `@Query("{'debters.user.internal':false,'_id':''}")`
     `Debters findByIdAndDebtersUserInternalIsFalse(@Param("id") String id,);`